# Why is this unconfirmed?

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions, zero-confirmation

Can someone tell me how to get a confirmation please or cancel this;

e8c5489abcb60ecdb925ac880ec1e238c9a65ca4c5480065a6ca268bf00ea7ba-000

Answer (score 4):

This transaction ([e8c5...](https://blockchain.info/tx/e8c5489abcb60ecdb925ac880ec1e238c9a65ca4c5480065a6ca268bf00ea7ba)) will never confirm because its inputs have already been spent by transaction [93cc4fe50e6069dccb827f56636bb4cd20f9865dd4d7e3b7946bbbca97576e80](https://blockchain.info/tx/93cc4fe50e6069dccb827f56636bb4cd20f9865dd4d7e3b7946bbbca97576e80), which currently has 9 confirmations.

There isn't any inherent need to cancel transaction e8c5; the network is never going to consider it valid.  You might want to remove it from your wallet client software in order to avoid having it display an incorrect balance or other confusion.  How to do that will depend on what software you are using.